# New files using Visual Studio, Bitbucket and SourceTree are not added on project

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, bitbucket, sourcetree

I have an annoying problem with integration of SourceTree, Bitbucket and Visual Studio.When i create a folder, class or Reference in my project and pushed to bitbucket,they dont are automatically added to other project when pushed.They are in the folder but dont are added in project.I already looking for answers here in Stack Overflow but no one helps me.As you can see in image,the "Teste" folder are not included in my Visual Studio project.How figure it out? Thanks

[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj93M.png)

[Visual Studio Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Taxi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happens because the files where not being included in `.csproj` , this could happens because the order of the git commit, you can change the order of the commit , or rebuild your project before the commit , this will automatically add the classes in `.csproj`

Also you can give some attention to the `.gitattributes` file to use a slightly different merge driver.

```
*.csproj -text merge=union
*.sln -text merge=union`
```

If you wanna read more about you can click [Here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).